# How to unit test variable reassignment in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

**Main question**: What is the most efficient way to unit test whether a class variable (`self.file_path`) was successfully reassigned by a method given the below class?

```
class FileHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path     # /original/path/file.csv

    def reassign_path(new_path):
        self.file_path = new_path      # /new/path/file.csv
        self.run_long_operation(self.file_path)
```

I initially tried testing whether the `self.file_path` variable was different after running the `reassign_path()`, but that method takes a very long time to finish and dramatically slows down testing.

**Secondary questions**:Is there a way to simply check whether a method reassigns a class variable without running the entire method? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Theoretically, you could analyze the Abstract Syntax Tree of your code to check that, using the built-in `ast` module. This won't make any of your code run.

Comment: You could mock the long operation

Comment: @JETM - could you expand on how I could mock the long operation? Sorry, I'm pretty new to mocks and unit testing.

Comment: @chepner's answer says it better than I would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not claiming the is the *best* solution, but it is test-friendly. It's similar to mocking the slow operation, but more explicit and tests the function using its defined interface, rather than making implementation-specific assumptions about what to mock.

Instead of hard-coding the long, slow operation, make it an argument to `reassign_path`.

```
class FileHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path

    def reassign_path(self, new_path, f=FileHandler.run_long_operation):
        self.file_path = new_path
        f(self, self.file_path)
```

Now, you can test `reassign_path` quickly by passing another, faster function as the second argument:

```
def test_reassign_path_quickly(self):
     fh = FileHandler('/old/path')
     fh.reassign_path('/new/path', lambda *args: None)
     self.assertEquals(fh.file_path, '/new/path')
```